# railsで新規登録フォームを作成し、RSpecで名前が空欄の時に失敗するというテストを書いた際に、have_current_pathで失敗後の遷移先として新規登録画面を期待するというテストを書いたのですが、なぜか一覧画面を期待してしまいテストが失敗してしまいます。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

実行環境
rails 7.0.3
ruby 3.1.2
rspec 3.11

ブラウザで操作した際には期待したpathに遷移することが確認できるのですが、RSpecのsystemテストでは期待したpathになっておらず、テストが落ちてしまいます。

著者の名前を登録するだけのシンプルなフォームのテストで名前が空欄の時には、エラーメッセージが表示され、新規登録画面をレンダリングするというテストでなぜ失敗するのかわからず質問させていただきます。

#### 実装内容

routes.rb

```rb
resources :authors
```

app/model/author.rb

```rb
validates :name, presence: true
```

app/controller/authors_controller

```rb
def new
  @author = Author.new
end

def create
  @author = Author.new(author_params)
  if @author.save
   redirect_to authors_path, notice: "#{@author.name}を登録しました"
  else
    render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end

private

def author_params
  params.require(:author).permit(:name)
end
```

app/views/authors/new.html.haml

```rb
= simple_form_for @author do |f|
  = f.input :name
  = f.button :submit
```

spec/system/authors_spec.rb

```rb
   context '必須項目の名前が入力されていない時' do
      it '作成できない' do
        visit new_author_path
        click_button '登録する'

        expect(page).to have_content '著者名を入力してください'
        expect(page).to have_current_path new_author_path
      end
    end
```

上記の`author_spec.rb`の実行結果が著者の一覧画面を期待するとなってしまい、失敗します。

`1) 著者の新規登録 必須項目の名前が入力されていない時 作成できない Failure/Error: expect(page).to have_current_path new_author_path expected "/authors" to equal "/authors/new"`

Answer (score 0):

自分は経験が浅いですが、気になったので書き込みました。
ユーザーログインをして登録というかたちでしょうか？
ユーザー作成、ログインなどの記載がみられていないところから、
ログインしていないので、一覧画面に遷移しているのかと思いました。
検討違いなことを言っていたら申し訳ないです。

Comment: ログインなどは一旦無視した実装になっているので、今回の原因ではなさそうです。

Answer (score 0):

> ブラウザで操作した際には、期待したpathに遷移することが確認できる

確認:
これは「著者名を入力してください」が表示されている画面の URL パスが `/authors/new` になっているということでしょうか? 表示される画面の内容は /authors/new テンプレートの内容であるものの、URL パスは `/authors` であったりしないでしょうか?

説明:
通常 routes.rb で `resources :authors` とすると `create` アクションは `post /authors` と関連付けられます。そして `create` アクションではエラー、つまり `@author.save` が `falsy` の場合は `redirect_to` せず `render :new` しています。これは `post /auhtors` によって authors/new テンプレートを表示するものなので、URL パスは `/authors` から変わらないはずです。

また、この URL パスは一覧 = `index` アクション = `get /authors`と同じものであり、実際にテストで actual value として報告されているものです。

> ブラウザで操作した際には、期待したpathに遷移することが確認できる

繰り返しになりますが、エラー発生時の path は `/authors` ※1 になっていないでしょうか? 表示される内容は authors/new テンプレートのもの※2 だと思います。
※1 `create` アクション `post /authors` の HTTP メソッドを除いた URL パス
※2 `render :new` の結果

補足:
なのでテストとしては次の 2点を expect することになると思います。

- URL パスは authros_path であること
- ページの内容が新規登録画面フォームであること

Answer (score 0):

> これは「著者名を入力してください」が表示されている画面の URL パスが /authors/new になっているということでしょうか?

そうです。

> 表示される画面の内容は /authors/new テンプレートの内容であるものの、URL パスは /authors であったりしないでしょうか?

著者の作成に失敗すると、エラーメッセージが表示され、エラー発生時のURLパスもちゃんと /authors/newになっています。

Comment: 補足情報などは、回答として投稿するのではなく、質問を編集して追記して下さい。